# How to call the refreshing of data-aware (live-binding) component in FireMonkey?

Tags: listview, delphi, firemonkey, firedac, livebindings

I have a `TListView` linked in LiveBindings with a `TFDMemTable`. I load data in the FDMemTable using `LoadFromFile` (I have for example 20 record).

When I delete a record from the FDMemTable, the `RecordCount` is decreased but the `TListView` is not refreshed, it continue to display the 20 records loaded on the `LoadFormFile`.

If, with the FDMemTable: I `.SaveToFile`, `.Close`, and reload with `.LoadFromFile`, the `TListView` now display the change.

This is the same behavior if I use the `CachedUpdate` of FDMemTable or not.

I've tried to call `TFDMemTable.Refresh` and `TListView.Repaint` without succes.

Is it possible to call the `TListView` to refresh his "linked" set of data ?

When I delete a record in the FDMemTable, why no visible refresh occur on the `TListView` ?

EDIT: 
I must add a thing, the record is deleted programmatically.

The desired functionality is to delete sone unwanted record in the `FDMemTable` and display the remaining record to the user with the `TListView`.

Comment: @Fabrizio:  Uh?  Isn't the whole idea of live bindings is to be able to use non-db-aware components with datasets ...

Comment: @MartynA Ops, I misread, sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In LiveBindings Designer, by linking the `Synch` of the `ListView` to the `*` of the `FDMemTable`, the `ListView` now display the resulting record.

[image: LiveBindings Designer]

Also in my last algorithm, because I use `.BeginBatch / .EndBatch` (that disable data-aware refreshing), while processing data for removing unwanted record I've to disable the LiveBinding link temporarily (cause I use different sorting index whitin the processing of the data): `LinkListControlToField1.Active := false;` and "re-link" it after processing: `LinkListControlToField1.Active := true;`

Answer (score 2):

The livebindings isn't consistently bi-directional here. The ListView livebindings was designed to work from the UI to the dataset direction, but only mostly.

If you enable `CanSwipeDelete`, you can expect that to work, if you know how.

In my case, on Android, I found myself writing code to ensure that the listview kept sync with the dataset, even though there is livebindings active. In my case is  a TClientDataset named CDSAnimals, with a unique key value of TagID. I hope this helps.

```
procedure TfrmLiveMain.ListView1DeletingItem(Sender: TObject; AIndex: Integer;
  var ACanDelete: Boolean);
var
  LI: TListViewItem;
  LIO: TListItemText;
begin

  // check that the livebindings is doing it's job, if not
  // do it myself
  ACanDelete := False;
  LI := ListView1.Items[AIndex];
  LIO := LI.Objects.FindObjectT<TListItemText>('Text1');
  FTagID := LIO.Text;
  if ClientModule2.CDSAnimals.FieldByName('TagID').AsString <> FTagID then
    ClientModule2.CDSAnimals.Locate('TagID', FTagID, []);
  if ClientModule2.CDSAnimals.FieldByName('TagID').AsString = FTagID then
  begin
    ACanDelete := True; // causes the listview item to be deleted without
                        // affecting the corresponding dataset record
  end;

end;

procedure TfrmLiveMain.ListView1DeleteItem(Sender: TObject; AIndex: Integer);
begin

  // this is called with the wrong index!
  if ClientModule2.CDSAnimals.Locate('TagID', FTagID, []) then
    if ClientModule2.CDSAnimals.FieldByName('TagID').AsString = FTagID then
      begin
        // now delete the corresponding record too
        ClientModule2.CDSAnimals.Delete; // and it works!
      end;

end;
```

Comment: Your idea drive me to a possible workaroud: deleting the item object of the `TListView` WHILE deleting record in the `TFDMemTable`. I don't know if it's a bug in Delphi but I've tried with some TMS component and this problem do not occur.

Comment: Another workaround is to work with 2 `TFDMemTable`, One for process the deleting of unwanted record and one for display (using LiveBindings) then usigng `CopyDataSet` to copy the process dataset in the display dataset. This is working (we must `.Close` the display dataset before unsing `CopyDataSet`).

Comment: Did you ever encounter any of the errors mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69791689/how-to-delete-a-database-record-linked-to-a-listview-item)? this happens after calling `delete` on the dataset record and LiveBinding is trying to delete the `listViwItem` that doesn't exist anymore.