# How to delete a database record linked to a listview item?

Tags: listview, delphi, firemonkey

I built a multi-device app using FireMonkey.

I have a ListView Live-Binded to a DB. Both synched by `*`.

It all works normally until I left wipe an item to delete. The item can be deleted, but the DB record is not.

So following  Doug Rudd advice, implemented following code to store DBID and locate the deleting Item.

```
procedure TPassPlus.LinkListControlToField1FilledListItem(Sender: TObject;
  const AEditor: IBindListEditorItem);
begin
     (AEditor.CurrentObject as TListItem).Tag :=
     DB_Table.FieldByName('DBID').AsInteger;
end;



myDBID:=     ListView1.Selected.Tag.ToString;
if DB_Table.Locate('DBID',myDBID,[]) then DB_Table.delete;
```

It worked well to delete the DB record. However, when ListView1DeletingItem event finished, it generated a 'Argument out of range' error, which can be traced into  TPresentedListView.DoDeleteItem event. It looks like, when DB record deleted, Listview has deleted the correspoding item, so when ListView1DeletingItem event finished, ListView has nothing to delete. What is the solution?

I was trying to decouple the link between the DB and Listview at runtime so I can delete the record and re-link the two.
I tried following code as a test.

```
   procedure TPassPlus.ListView1DeletingItem(Sender: TObject; AIndex: Integer;
      var ACanDelete: Boolean);
    begin 
        ListView1.BeginUpdate;
      BindSourceDB1.DataSource.DataSet.close;
    //or LinkListControlToField1.Active:=false;
        ListView1.EndUpdate;
end;
```

On either case, it will produce 'Argument out of range' error.
I think LiveBinding suppose to bridge UI and Dataset, Deleting an item of Listview natually should delete the bound data record. If not, what is the point of using LiveBinding? No wonder so many negative comments on LiveBiding. It cannot implement some basic UI-Data binding function.
Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Can you store the DB record ID in the ListView item? Then you could use that to delete the DB record when the item is being deleted.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that using a hidden TTextObjectAppearance storing the DBID in the list item, then take it out on OnDeleteItem event. The listview is in DynamicAppearance. taking one field value seems not easy, plus this suppose to be an easy function, or either the ListVIew.Delete or LiveBingding doesn't work as it should do. Is this a bug or wrong way of coding?

Comment: ListView is not meant to delete a record from the database when you delete the ListItem. You have to do that manually. You can store the ID of the record in the ListItem.Tag in LiveBindings.

Comment: Thanks @Doug Rudd for your advice. According to yours, implemented above code and managed to delete the DB record. But I encountered another issue, Argument out range. I traced the flow, and found out : after finishing ListView1DeletingItem event, FMX did TPresentedListView.DoDeleteItem and ,there, it has this error. Obviously when I delete the DB record, it already deleted the ListItem as well. So, when ListView1DeletingItem event finished, TPresentedListView.DoDeleteItem has nothing to delete. What shall I do in this case?

Comment: @Haizhou I can't say anything but that I have the same issue with no solution yet. If you managed to find a solution kindly share it with others.